# $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] over time()

Tags: php

What I stumbled upon seems pretty interesting and awakened my curiosity. I read in a micro optimization article that it would be smart to use the anyway present `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` instead of calling `time()` when I need a UNIX timestamp. I would like to ask if this is firstly reliable, if I'm certain that my application will always run under HTTP, and secondly would it be smart to overwrite the default `time()` function to

```
function time(){
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
}
```

Because refactoring - ain't nobody got time fo' dat!

Comment: Any micro-optimisation gained by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` would probably be lost if you create a new function to get that value.

Comment: Well **if** default `time()` is calculating seconds by multiplying days since 1970 by 86400 or something similar, it just makes no sense to still be faster instead of creating another function. I'm not trying to argue just thinking :?

Comment: I highly doubt that `time()` is doing anything more than call `time +%s` on the system.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: even if it performed some calculation - it is still not as heavy as defining a new function and invoking it.

Comment: Well I guess that's why it's called a COMPUTEr, silly me!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's what it does actually: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1739 http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense, however this is not correct. Because the time you get using `time()` is the current accurate system time, whereas `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` is a constant populated by PHP when the page was requested. If the page takes time to load and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` is called in the end, there will be a difference between the values of `time()` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`.

Also overriding `time()` wont be a good idea. Because when calling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` directly, there is no stack maintained by php, but when overriding `time()` (always in your code weather its called or not) will cost much more in terms of system resources from an application architectural point of view.