# Mocking a method with prophet

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Assume there is a method

```
public function updateTimestamp($sessionId, $data)
{
    return $this->memcached->touch($sessionId, time() + $this->ttl);
}
```

that I'd like to test. [Infection](https://infection.github.io/guide/) changes the **`+`** in `time() + $this->ttl` to **`-`** and all my tests are still passing. So I'd like to make a test that will mock Memcached's touch in it and will conditionally return `true`/`false` basing on the second argument passed to it.

So doing something like:

```
    // $ttl is set;
    $memcachedMock
        ->touch(
            'sessionId',
            $certainValuePassedToTouch
        )
        ->willReturn(
            $certainValuePassedToTouch >= time() + $ttl 
                ? true 
                : false
        )
        ;
```

There are two problems now:

1. I don't know how to make such a condition for an arbitrary integer parameter passed to the method being mocked
2. basing on time() seems to be very unreliable, so how can I reliably test it if time() is used in the method itself?

Comment: sorry to side-track a little (more about 2.): the test is already flaky because of `time()` as a hidden dependency in the SUT. consider mocking time first. an *easy* way in PHP is to make use of the super global `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` over `time()` sparing syscalls, too (and superglobals are easily modifed in tests). Your mileage may vary though. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26083425/367456 and *other* Q&A as well as the PHP docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't change the code in the method being tested, it's extended from https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MemcachedSessionHandler.php . And the example of mocking touch was just an idea, I don't know if I need to rely on time() at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can you take a look on this tools :

- https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock
- https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock-phpunit

Based on PHP's namespace fallback policy (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php), it allow to mock php native functions like time(), date(), etc.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very useful (meaning mocking native PHP functions like time() ) ! Will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary parameters you could take a look at [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library. It generates arbitrary fake data for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the `time()` function to return `0` and the return value of the `touch()` method will depend solely on the `$ttl` value. For the first, there are suggestions in other answers, and the second can be archived with `returnCallback()`.

```
$memcachedMock
    ->method('touch')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($key, $val) {
        return $val > 0;
    }));
```